# Failed connect MySQL to VS code. Authentication Method Does Not Match Against Authentication Policy

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-code

I want to connect MySQL to VSCode, and some of tutorial said that I have to change user authentication method with the native one.
so I do this,
alter user 'username'@'%' identified with mysql_native_password by 'mypassword';

I Get this warning

0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 4058 1 factor authentication method does not match against authentication policy. Please refer @@authentication_policy system variable.

How could I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: which extension are you using in vscode to connect to `mysql`

Comment: SQL tools and SQL tools mysql/MariaDB